# linux - Convert txt file with entries on different lines to .csv?

Tags: linux, csv, txt

I have used exiftool to make .txt files with the EXIF data of some images and videos I am working with. I will also eventually need to create .csv manifests for these files, and I know there are simple ways to convert .txt files to .csv files, but the instructions I've found have described how to do so if the .txt file has the information to go in different columns within the same line, while mine are on different lines. Is there a way to do this conversion with .txt files that are organized differently?

For example, I have seen instructions for how to convert something like this

```
filename   date       size
abc.JPG    1/1/2001   1MB
def.JPG    1/1/2001   1MB
hij.JPG    1/1/2001   1MB
```

to

```
filename,date,size
abc.JPG,1/1/2001,1MB
def.JPG,1/1/2001,1MB
hij.JPG,1/1/2001,1MB
```

The .txt files I have, on the other hand, are formatted like this:

```
========abc.JPG
File Name            abc.JPG
Date/Time Original   2001:01:01 1:00:00
Size                 1 MB
========def.JPG
File Name            def.JPG
Date/Time Original   2001:01:01 1:01:00
Size                 1 MB
========hij.JPG
File Name            hij.JPG
Date/Time Original   2001:01:01 1:02:00
Size                 1 MB
```

but I still need an output like

```
filename,date,size
abc.JPG,2001:01:01 1:00:00,1 MB
def.JPG,2001:01:01 1:01:00,1 MB
hij.JPG,2001:01:01 1:02:00,1 MB
```

Comment: You can do it easily with `awk`. What have you tried?

Comment: I've looked at an example of an ```awk``` command but I'm not sure how to format it for what I need if that makes sense? One problem is that from what I've seen, ```awk``` makes rows in the .csv file from the different lines in the .txt file, but I need rows to go into columns (in terms of when you open the .csv file in Excel or something like that). The other problem is that I have a lot of metadata for each image in the .txt file as well as a lot of images, so having to manually put in the number for each line that I want would be far too tedious.

Comment: `awk` can do whatever you program it to do. You can set variables on each line, and when you get to the last line of the group you print a single line with all the variables.

Comment: You tell `awk` to match the lines beginning with different strings and only process those lines. It will ignore all the other metadata.

Comment: E.g. `awk '/^File Name/ { filename = $3 } /^Date/ { date = $3 " " $4 }` and so on

Comment: Is there a way to get all the metadata, like some kind of "all" command? I think my issue is more that I don't know how to get the output to have things that are on different lines on the .txt file be in separate columns but the same row in the .csv file

Comment: It's not so much that I need to pick and choose which metadata goes into the .csv, more that I need it to be organized differently than in the .txt file.

Comment: There's no built-in solution, you have to write this ad hoc code.

Comment: This is not a standard file format with a predefined parser.

Comment: Is there a consistent delimiter between the field names and values, like a `TAB`?

Answer (score 0):

Using sed and [Miller](https://github.com/johnkerl/miller), you can run

```
<input.txt sed -r 's/==.+//g;s/([a-zA-Z]) ([a-zA-Z])/\1-\2/' | mlr --x2c label filename,date,size >output.csv
```

to have

```
filename,date,size
abc.JPG,2001:01:01 1:00:00,1 MB
def.JPG,2001:01:01 1:01:00,1 MB
hij.JPG,2001:01:01 1:02:00,1 MB
```